# Nested while does not work as expected

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.One table is `the_temp` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbbae/1 and the other table is `members` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afaab3/1

The `members` table holds all the members of the clubs and `the_temp` is just a temporary table where records are looked into before they can be added into the members table.

The rule is a member `cannot be in two clubs in the same year`.

To solve that problem,i am taking a record at a time from `the_temp` and running it against every record in the `members` table using this stored procedure.

If a member in the `temp_table` is found to be in another club in the `members` table for a given year,then,he/she is marked as `fail` in `the_temp`'s `the_temp_status` column.

This is the stored procedure

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE leshex()
BEGIN

DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE the_temp_name VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE lestemp VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE lesmember VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE the_temp_club_id VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE the_temp_membership_year VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE member_name VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE member_club_id VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE membership_year VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 0;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM the_temp INTO n;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members into x;

SET lesmember=0;
SET lestemp=0;

WHILE lestemp<n DO 
select the_temp_name into the_temp_name from the_temp where the_temp_id=lestemp;
select the_temp_club_id into the_temp_club_id from the_temp where the_temp_id=lestemp;
select the_temp_membership_year into the_temp_membership_year from the_temp where the_temp_id=lestemp;

WHILE lesmember<x DO
select member_name into member_name from members where member_id=lesmember;
select member_club_id into member_club_id from members where member_id=lesmember;
select membership_year into membership_year from members where member_id=lesmember;

IF EXISTS(select member_club_id from members 
where member_club_id in (1,2) AND member_name=the_temp_name AND membership_year=the_temp_membership_year)

THEN

update the_temp SET the_temp_status='fail' where the_temp_name=member_name;

else

update the_temp SET the_temp_status='pass' where the_temp_name=member_name;
END IF;
END WHILE;

END WHILE;
/* 
Finally

insert into (member_name,member_club_id,membership_year) select the_temp_name,the_temp_club_id,the_temp_membership_year from the_temp where the_temp_status='pass';

*/
End;
;;
```

when i the stored procedure,it marks all records as `pass`,which is wrong,since i have a record in `the_temp` that fails.The stored procedure doesn't stop iterating and i killed it by

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
KILL n;
```

How should i correct this?.

Comment: how do you expect it to get out of the loop? `lestemp<n` both are constant in the loop. also `lesmember<x` both are constants in inner loop also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set `temp.status = 'fail'` when there are two memberships in the same year.

Wow.  That is an `update` query, that doesn't require any explicit looping:

```
update temp left outer join
       (select member_name, member_year, count(*) as cnt
        from members
        group by member_name, member_year
       ) my
       on temp.member_name = my.member_name and
          temp.the_temp_membership_year = my.member_year
  set temp.the_temp_status = (case when cnt is null or cnt = 1 then 'pass' else 'fail' end);
```

Let the database do the work of processing the data, using (primarily) joins and aggregations.  That is the power of relational databases.